# Docker - Cassandra

Tags: docker, cassandra

I'm trying to dockerize cassandra by following below steps.
Docker file ->

```
FROM oraclelinux:7.3
COPY apache-cassandra-2.2.8-bin.tar.gz /opt
RUN cd /opt && tar -xvzf apache-cassandra-2.2.8-bin.tar.gz
RUN cd /opt && ln -s apache-cassandra-2.2.8 cassandra
RUN cd /opt/cassandra && mkdir data && mkdir commitlog && mkdir saved_caches
COPY cassandra.yaml /opt/cassandra/conf
COPY cassandra-topology.properties /opt/cassandra/conf
RUN chmod +x /opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra
ENV CASSANDRA_CONFIG /opt/cassandra/conf
ENV CASSANDRA_HOME /opt/cassandra
RUN /opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra"]
EXPOSE 7000 7001 7199 9160
```

When I build cassandra docker using

```
docker build -t my_cassandra .
```

throws below error message

```
Step 19/21 : RUN /opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra
---> Running in 36bd332c523a
cat: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf: No such file or directory
```

When I build cassandra docker using

```
docker run -it my_cassandra bin/bash
```

it throws same error message

```
cat: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf: No such file or directory
```

If I remove the ENTRYPOINT line or hash it out, docker builds and runs fine but cassandra doesn't run as part of docker run command. I have to logon to the container and manually start with ./cassandra

Is there a way I could start cassandra as part of docker run command here?

Comment: Can you just post the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: You might be better off with some existing image: https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/

Comment: @Andy, I have edited the above section to docker file code

Comment: @Marko, wanted to try like regular cassandra install/config

Comment: A word of advice out of the experience! We have done performance evaluation on dockerized cassandra over bare metal. We have seen significant performance degradation for dockerized cassandra. Also, persistence is the most important piece of database technology. your examples above doesn't take care of the volumes.

Answer (score 0):

From your example above, it doesn't look like ENTRYPOINT is the problem here. You should not run Cassandra as part of the Docker build.

`Step 19/21 : RUN /opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra
---> Running in 36bd332c523a
cat: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf: No such file or directory`

Remove `RUN /opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra`.

Take a look at the official Cassandra Docker Image on Docker Hub.

link: [Official Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/a78f0c2c40507f31a6b5048d029e77f5e3e5054b/2.1/Dockerfile)

link: [Docker Hub - Cassandra](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/)

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to the upstream image you use. `/opt/cassandra/bin/cassandra` seems to be a shell script which executes `which ldconfig` at some point. If `which` is missing from your image, you will see such error